# What values to use for A2 paper size in Microsoft gpd file?

Tags: paper, paper-size

I hope this question could be answered here.

I need to understand what values should be chosen for A2 size.

Per [this Franklin Heath article](https://franklinheath.co.uk/2015/08/29/custom-page-sizes-for-microsoft-print-to-pdf/) and [this one at Microsoft Answers](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-hardware-winpc/microsoft-print-to-pdf-custom-paper-sizes-possible/90ed3d48-1ece-4ca5-8d3b-ff0af24a7b37):

A3 and A4 size are specified by microsoft PDF writer as

A3 : *PrintableArea: PAIR(5346000, 7560000)

A4 : *PrintableArea: PAIR(3780000, 5346000)

With that I am not able to figure out the A2 size

[Stephen Wiltshire](https://www.stephenwiltshire.co.uk/paper-sizes) specifies A2, A3 and A4 as

> The A2 size print measures 42.0 x 59.4cm, 16.53 x 23.39 inches, if
> mounted 59.4 x 76.6cm, 23.39 x 30.16 inches.
>
> The A3 size print measures 29.7 x 42.0cm, 11.69 x 16.53 inches, if
> mounted 40.6 x 50.8cm, 15.98 x 20 inches.
>
> The A4 size print measures 21.0 x 29.7cm, 8.27 x 11.69 inches, if
> mounted 30.3 x 40.6cm, 11.93 x 15.98 inches.

I am not able to figure out what unit the values are in the gpd file

**Note** : I used 7560000, 10690900 initially and after I received the answer, I changed to 7560000, 10692000

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The beauty of the [A-paper size system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_216#A_series) (Wikipedia) is that for any of the A-sizes (A4, A3, etc.), the ratio of the long edge of the paper to the short edge is √2:1. Because of this particular ratio, each successively smaller size, such as A3 → A4, is obtained by cutting the larger page in half along its long dimension. Thus, A4's long dimension is just A3's short dimensions; and A4's short dimension is half of A3's long dimension.

[image]
<sup>*A series paper sizes*. From [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:A_size_illustration2.svg) by user [Bromskloss](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/User:Bromskloss). [CC BY-SA 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/deed.en)</sup>

Using pattern recognition, starting with your spec of `A3: *PrintableArea: PAIR(5346000 , 7560000)`, then your A2 pair should be **`756000`** and `5346000 * 2 =` **`10692000`**.

Comment: I used 7560000, 10690900 initially and now changed to 7560000, 10692000

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you divide the dimensions (in inches or cm or whatever) by the numbers from the software, you'll get the same value for each - e.g. 11.69 inches / 5346000 = 0.00000218668. If you then divide the dimensions for the A2 size by that number, you should get the values you need to plug into the software - which I calculate to be about 7559399 and 10696573, respectively. Although, obviously the software is using rounded-off values - so maybe 7559000 and 10697000. Not sure if those numbers are a specific unit of size, or just a general scaling factor, but the math isn't too difficult.